# How do I print the integer that is not 0?

Tags: java

Doing code for my java class, program runs as expected the only issue I'm having is if the interstate is, for example, 405 when it prints it prints 05 marking the question wrong because the question is just looking for 5 . Any help?

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 

      highwayNumber = scnr.nextInt();

      if ((highwayNumber > 999) || (highwayNumber < 1)) {
         System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
      }
      else if ((highwayNumber < 100) && (highwayNumber > 0) && (highwayNumber % 2 == 0)) {
         System.out.println("The " + highwayNumber + " is primary, going east/west.");
      }
      else if ((highwayNumber < 100) && (highwayNumber > 0) && (highwayNumber % 2 != 0)) {
         System.out.println("The " + highwayNumber + " is primary, going north/south.");
      }
      else if ((highwayNumber > 99) && (highwayNumber < 1000) && (highwayNumber % 2 == 0)) {
         System.out.println("The " + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving the " + String.valueOf(highwayNumber).substring(1) + ", going east/west.");
      }
      else if ((highwayNumber > 99) && (highwayNumber < 1000) && (highwayNumber % 2 != 0)) {
         System.out.println("The " + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving the " + String.valueOf(highwayNumber).substring(1) + ", going north/south.");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `String.valueOf(highwayNumber).substring(1)`, how about `(highwayNumber % 100)`?  Or,  `String.valueOf(highwayNumber % 100)`, if you prefer.

Comment: Not relevant to the result, but since you have already validated that the `highwayNumber` is between `1` and `999` in your first `if` block, all the `(highwayNumber > 0)` and `(highwayNumber < 1000)` conditions in subsequent `else if` blocks are redundant.

Comment: *"for example, 405 when it prints it prints 05 marking the question wrong because the question is just looking for 5"* - You need to explain clearly what the requirements ask for.  Is that wrong because it expects the last digit, or because it expects the last two digits without a leading zero?   Note: the correct correction to your code will depend on the requirements!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `substring` with `%` modulus operator:

```
System.out.println("The " + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving the " + String.valueOf(highwayNumber % 100) + ", going east/west.");

System.out.println("The " + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving the " + String.valueOf(highwayNumber % 100) + ", going north/south.");
```